# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) doesn't work after long period of inactivity in Android app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM to send push notifications to my Android app. It works normally when I open the app or when I have just recently navigated away from the app. But if I wait some longer period of time, (e.g. I go to sleep and wake up in the morning) the app no longer receives push notifications. Once I open the app again, it receives notifications just fine (but not the ones sent during the period of inactivity).

I'm aware of some delay in receiving GCM notifications. [Android: Unable to receive GCM Messages/ Listener not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305507/android-unable-to-receive-gcm-messages-listener-not-being-called) (up to 30 min or so). But I'm not receiving the message at all.

Comment: Check this SO question [31655798](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655798/gcm-notification-received-after-hours-on-some-devices) and [11681455](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681455/android-gcm-messages-take-too-long-to-come) if it can help you:)

Answer (score 0):

TCP Keepalive time-out needs to be configured

Comment: Can you give some more direction or link to more resources on how to accomplish this? Like where is this TCP Keepalive time-out configured? On Android? On my server? On GCM?